Searching in an unsorted array, where range of the elements in given
I have an array, denoted as A, containing integers. The range of these integers falls within the interval [1, 10^6], and the size of the array is approximately 50,000 elements. My objective is to determine whether a given number, denoted as 'x' (where 1 <= x <= 10^6), exists within the array and, if so, to retrieve its index.
Currently, I've implemented a solution by maintaining an additional array of size 10^6. This auxiliary array serves to map each element value to its corresponding index within array A. While this approach offers optimal time complexity for searches, it necessitates considerable extra space, amounting to 10^6 units. I'm seeking an alternative solution that achieves the same functionality while minimizing the required space to a value below 10^6.

Are you allowed to modify the array?

Yes we can modify A, given the search queries should work. Forgot to mention that the elements in A is not present all at once. Initially the number of elements would be 0 , we would insert the integers (at the end only) in A, as well as search them. But the max size of the A is fixed.

The less memory you use, the more algorithmic power (and time) you need. If memory needs to be minimised, then sort the array and use binary search.

@trincot That was exactly my thought. :-)

Which language you are using?
In C# you can use Dictionary.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] A = { 5, 2, 7, 10, 3, 8, 1, 6, 4, 9 };

        // Create a Dictionary to store the mapping between element value and its index in A
        Dictionary<int, int> indexMap = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        // Populate the Dictionary
        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            // Check if the element already exists in the Dictionary
            if (!indexMap.ContainsKey(A[i]))
            {
                // If not, add it to the Dictionary
                indexMap.Add(A[i], i);
            }
        }

        // Test cases
        int[] testCases = { 3, 8, 11 };

        foreach (int x in testCases)
        {
            if (indexMap.ContainsKey(x))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Number {x} found at index {indexMap[x]}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Number {x} not found");
            }
        }
    }
}

Explanation:
I create a Dictionary "indexMap", the key is the element value and the value is its index in array A.
Then I iterate through array A and populate the Dictionary.
Finally, to check if a number is present in the array and get its index, we simply check if "indexMap" contains the key.
Or you can try using Hashset.

Do you have evidence that this will use less memory than the solution that the asker had already tried with? They are asking for a solution that uses less memory.

According to the solution you have described in the question, you are using an additional array of size 10^6.
While using HashSet or Dictionary, it has this space complexity:
Space required for the HashSet: O(n), where n is the size of array A (which is approximately 50k in your case).
Space required for storing the index of each element: O(n), because in the worst-case scenario, each element in A may have a unique index.
And on the solution that I shared: it only stores mappings for the elements that are actually present in array A. So it's O(n)

I am using C  language
